# How can i use a method within its own class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

The function "uparcurriculo" is activated when i access my "Empregos" route through POST method. I wish i could do all the stuff i need in uparcurriculo and then in the end just call the index function, but that is not working. When i do this, a blank page is returned to me.

Am i doing this right?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Doutrinas;
use DB;

class EmpregosController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    public function index()  {

        return view('empregos/empregos')->with('mensagemSucesso', 'Você está na tela de empregos!');

    }

    public function uparcurriculo()  {

        //i also tried the line bellow and it doesn't work
        //Self::index();

        $this->index();

    }

}
```

Comment: Add a `return` statement: `return $this->index();`

Comment: I would recommend returning a redirect to the route for the index method rather than just calling the index method.